# Using Leaflet.awesome-markers with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, leaflet

How can I get [Leaflet.awesome-markers](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers) to work with Rails? Awesome Markers can't find the icons that I saved in the `vendor/assets/images` directory. I previously dealt with Leaflet's trouble finding icon images by using the `image_path` method:

```
var icon = L.icon({iconUrl: '<%= image_path("marker-icon.png") %>',
                   shadowUrl: '<%= image_path("marker-shadow.png") %>'
                  });
```

I don't see any way of doing this with Awesome Markers, however. Is there perhaps some Rails asset-pipeline hack to get around this? If there isn't any way of getting Awesome Markers to work with Rails, is there an alternative way of displaying icons on Leaflet markers (preferably one that that uses Font Awesome)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into [`leaflet.awesome-markers.css.scss`](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/blob/2.0/develop/dist/leaflet.awesome-markers.css) and change all the URLs to Sass asset-pipeline URLs. Example:

```
background: url('images/markers-soft.png') no-repeat 0 0;

/* change to */

background: image-url('markers-soft.png') no-repeat 0 0;
```

Make sure you add the `.scss` extension to the Awesome Markers style sheet. [This gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) might help if font-awesome itself isn't working.